# Call to subprocess only works with PyCharm debugger

Tags: python, python-2.7, grep, subprocess, pycharm

I have made a Python script in which one line makes a call to `grep` through `subprocess`:

```
master_start_time = subprocess.check_output(["grep", "-a", '"Time"', master_wav]).strip()[-23:]
```

When I run it using my Python interpreter (v. 2.7.12), the following error consistently appears, both when executing from PyCharm and through a remote shell (as the script and data reside on a remote machine running Ubuntu 16.04.1):

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['grep', '-a', '"Time"', './DATA/PREDICTING/1014/1014_L.wav']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Once I run the script through a remote PyCharm debugger, however, everything runs smoothly.

The following lines appear first in the PyCharm console when debugging. They should summarize the debug configuration.

```
ssh://{user}@{server}:{port}{path to interpreter} -u {path to PyCharm debugger} --multiproc --qt-support --client '0.0.0.0' --port 35567 --file {path to script}
pydev debugger: process 18838 is connecting
```

Does anyone know how I can prevent this from appearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out what had to be done was to remove the double quotes around the word `Time` in the subprocess call.

```
master_start_time = subprocess.check_output(["grep", "-a", 'Time', master_wav]).strip()[-23:]
```

Comment: I had a similar problem with a similar solution.  In my case I was calling Python in a subprocess (in order to run a different version of Python).  I had an extra set of double quotes in the 3rd argument which wasn't necessary.
I think what's going on here is that PyCharm, when configured to attach a debugger to subprocesses, actually fixes this for you (probably accidentally).  Obviously this doesn't happen if you're not running in debug mode.